# Create directory using an underscore

Tags: windows-7, windows

When attempting to create a directory, using a single underscore char, anywhere in the folder hierarchy, using both Explorer and a DOS prompt I receive 'Access is denied'.

I have also tried using ACSII code 95 without success.

I can a dir using two underscores, such as create c:__ and also i can create c:\test_.

How is that I cannot create the directory locally using this character?

Comment: Just as a thought, the error seems unlikely to be directly related to the use of an underscore as underscores aren't one of the [reserved characters in Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file). You may wish to edit your question to include more details about the actual path you are attempting to create.

Comment: I agree with @Anaksunaman -- if the error is "Access is denied", that is unrelated to the underscore. Can you post something showing your permissions for the directory in which you are trying to create this new directory?